# Strange white space appearing in page layout. What causes it?

Tags: css

On the website http://www.northkingdom.com/, when the browser window is narrower than 568 pixels (or on mobile), and you click on the menu button in the top right corner, there is a narrow, vertical, **white space** to the right of the list:

[image]

#### What creates this white space?

I cannot find any CSS rules or page elements that keep the menu from sitting at the right edge of the screen.

Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is an `overflow-y:scroll`in here:`header.mobile-menu #nav`.

That white space is actually a scrollbar. You can replace it with auto instead of scroll

Comment: Agreed, you beat me to it Nick

Comment: Thank you. IS there any reason why I shouldn't delete that rule completely? Are there browsers that don'

Comment: You can try to remove it. Having the overflow-y allows the menu to be scrolled vertically if needed. It may scroll even without that property, it depends on other elements of your design. I think you can try to remove it if you want and check that everything works fine

Comment: @Nick Thank you for your help. Sorry for bothering you with this, but did you even see that white scroll bar when you visites thw site? I'm confused because now that I have shut down and turned on my computer for lunch that scrollbar is gone without any change to the code. I wonder if it was caused by something in my browser cache or something in anothwr tab (I've often had JS interfering across tabs).

Comment: Yea i've seen it. It was there, i opened the inspector and removed the class that i mentioned in my answer and it disappeared...

Answer (score 0):

Thats a scrollbar, not a white space. Add this to your css of your `ul` and you will not have the problem anymore

`overflow: hidden;`